# Django cannot find my templatetags, even though it's in INSTALLED_APPS and has a __init__.py

Tags: django, django-templates

I just installed [django-compress](http://code.google.com/p/django-compress) into /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/compress.

I added `'compress'` to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

In my template file, I wrote `{% load compressed %}`.  I got the error:

> 'compressed' is not a valid tag
>   library: Could not load template
>   library from
>   django.templatetags.compressed, No
>   module named compressed

I verified that there is an `__init__.py` in compress, as well as in `compress/templatetags/`.  I tried putting the compress directory into PYTHONPATH.  I ran python and wrote `import compress` and that worked.

What else can I try?

Comment: Is there a file name `compressed.py` in the templatetags folder?

Comment: @czarchaic - if not then he's doing it wrong (http://code.google.com/p/django-compress/source/browse/trunk/compress/templatetags/compressed.py)

Comment: are you running stand alone development server or as a WSGI component.

Comment: Have you solved this? I'm facing same issue now...

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the solution. Probably you got the source code from google code which is no longer maintained repository (as stated in docs). The newest version is available at: http://github.com/pelme/django-compress

After switch to this one everything works fine.

Comment: Confusingly, that's a different package. django-compressor has a tag library named "compress" whereas django-compress (which is now deprecated) had a tag library named "compressed".